# Error: Cannot find the Style Property 'Template' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup'

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, popup

I have to create style for popups. I am using WPF and .NET Framework 4.

I have written style:

```
<Style x:Key="PopupBox" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">   
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">       
                <Grid>  
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                        <Grid>                                
                            <Border Background="AliceBlue"/>  
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" /> 
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Background="#FFBFDBFF"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have cut off from this code some elements like grid row and column definitions because they are not significant.

So it seems that I can't use `<Setter Property="Template">` because Popup control doesn't have this property. How can I work around this?

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Popup doesn`t have any template and just a `Child` property for content, you can use some other control (for example `ContentControl`) to style and template:

```
<Style x:Key="PopupContentStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                    <Grid>                                
                        <Border Background="AliceBlue"/>  
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Background="#FFBFDBFF"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then just place it in every `Popup` that needs it:

```
<Popup>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">
       <!-- Some content here -->
    </ContentControl>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Template can be set only for Controls which inherits from  `Control` class since Control class exposed the Template property. But since PopUp is inherited directly from `FrameworkElement` class, that's why you can't set its Template property. As a workaround you can set its Child property like this -

```
<Setter Property="Child">
        <Setter.Value>      
                <Grid>  
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                        <Grid>                                
                            <Border Background="AliceBlue"/>  
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" /> 
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Background="#FFBFDBFF"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid> 
        </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: With this approach it won\`t be possible to set `Popup` content in XAML, as it will override `Style` setting.

Comment: That's what Cassandra desired in the question i guess. He/She is trying to set the control template for its popup which ultimately overrides the default template on which this style is applied.

Comment: Judging by presence of `ContentPresenter` in Template, content in `Popup` must not be static. If you set `Child` in style, how can you add content to `Popup` itself without overriding that style?